# UVs Not Transferring to Texture Paint Mode

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I modeled a simple Batarang, and am trying to apply an image texture to it, whether via the shading window from an outside source, or by direct texture painting inside blender. I have unwrapped the UVs on seams that I need as shown below. As soon as I go into texture paint mode and select the same object. It has the basic cube t-pose UVs with all of my subdivisions. If I try to apply an outside image, it applies them on that basic cube UV, instead of my unwrapped ones. Do I need to apply the UVs from UV editor, I don't understand why they aren't transferring over to paint/shading. The oddly painted cube in the back was a test, and it worked fine. Unwrapped on all seams, and it transferred seamlessly to texture painter for live painting.

[image: Basic layout of UVs in UV Editing Mode]

[image: Same Object in Texture Paint has default subdivided UVs]

Comment: It looks like your uv editor is showing the cube unwrap and not your batarang model. Delete the cube and save, and reopen to see if it persists.

Comment: The batarang is just a subdivided / loop cut cube that I modeled from. What is showing in the texture paint window is what the UVs looked like in the UV Editor before the first time I marked seams and unwrapped. Yet, even after unwrapping, they are still showing as the default 6 sided cube with all of it's loop cuts and extrudes in the texture paint window.

Comment: Can you append your batarang to a new file to see how the UVs look there?